# How to change a variable in server machine using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I have few html pages on the server. I have designed a admin page and that page is also on the server. What my goal is that there is a button on the server page. If i click that button the index page will be redirected to an error,html page.
here is my code in the admin page

```
var isError=false;
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $("#turnon").hide();
      localStorage.setItem('isError', isError);
      $("#turnoff").on('click',function(){
        isError=true;
        localStorage.setItem('isError', isError);
        $("#adminmessage").text("The Site is Turned off");
        $("#turnon").show();
        $("#turnoff").hide();
      });

      $("#turnon").on('click',function(){
        isError=false;
        localStorage.setItem('isError', isError);
        $("#adminmessage").text("The Site is Turned on");
        $("#turnon").hide();
        $("#turnoff").show();
      });
    });
```

In the above code i am setting the localstorage variable.
I am checking the localstorage variable at the beginning of index.html page using the following code

```
var isError = localStorage.getItem('isError');
                if(isError==='true')
                    {
                    window.location="error.html";
                    }
```

But i see if i click the button the functionality works on which machine i have clicked the button. But if i go to the site from other machine its not redirected to the error page. It seems like that the variable is set in my local machine so that i am redirected to error page. So other users are not redirected to error page. Is there any way to set the variable in the server. So that all users accessing the page are redirected to the error page.

Comment: You're saving the variable in `localStorage`... _local_ storage. That variable isn't sent to the server.

Comment: Ya. I was thinking it stores the variable in the machine where the file is located. Am i wrong?

Comment: So is there any way to store the variable in the machine where the file is located i.e. the server machine?

Comment: What language are you using server-side?

Comment: I am using only javascript

Comment: You need a server in order to propagate the setting to all users.

Comment: To store any kind of data in the server you need to use a server side technology.